# FileSystemException (FileSystemException: Cannot create file, path = './skipwelcomedata_bad_keys.hive' (OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30))

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-hive

I have set up a data storage system with Hive in my Flutter application. After installing everything, I get this error:

```
FileSystemException (FileSystemException: Cannot create file, path = './skipwelcomedata_bad_keys.hive' (OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30))
```

What is this error? How can I solve it? Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  print("${directory.path}/db");
  // Hive.init(directory.path);
  collection ??= await BoxCollection.open(
    'AppName', // Name of your database
    {'images'}, // Names of your boxes
    path: "${directory.path}/db", // <-- this fixes it
  );
```

I noticed a bug, if you just put the documents directory it doesn't work because it won't add a slash to the end of the path. So you have to add something like /db after the slash. I don't if I was having a weird problem, but seemed to be the issue.